# advice about using rspec for testing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I just started using rspec and I'd like to have your opinion about this spec.
I have 2 models

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :department_id, :presence => true
  belongs_to :department
end
```

and

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  has_many :cities
end
```

I wrote down those spec in order to satisfy the validation and relationship statement:

city_spec.rb

```
describe City do

  before(:each) do
    @city = Factory(:city)
  end

  describe "validation" do
    it "valid" do
      @city.should be_valid
      @city.should have(:no).errors_on(:name)
      @city.should have(:no).errors_on(:department_id)
    end

    it "has a unique name" do
      c = Factory.build(:city, :name => @city.name)
      c.should_not be_valid
      c.name = 'unique'
      c.should be_valid
      # or via shoulda
      c.should validate_uniqueness_of(:name)
    end

    it "belongs to department" do
      c = Factory.build(:city, :department_id => nil)
      c.should have(1).error_on(:department_id)
      c.department_id = @city.department_id
      c.should be_valid
      c.should belong_to(:department)
    end
  end
end
```

department_spec.rb

```
describe Department do

  before(:each) do
    @department = Factory(:department)
  end

  describe "validation" do
   it "has a name" do
    d = Factory.build(:department, :name => nil)
    d.should_not be_valid
    d.should have(1).error_on(:name)
    d.name = 'good name'
    d.should be_valid
  end

  it "has a unique name" do
    d = Factory.build(:department, :name => @department.name)
    d.should_not be_valid
    d.name = 'good name'
    d.should be_valid
  end

  it "has many cities" do
    d = Factory.build(:department)
    c1 = Factory.build(:city)
    c2 = Factory.build(:city)
    d.cities << c1
    d.cities << c2
    d.cities.size.should == 2
    d.cities.first.should == c1
    d.cities.last.should == c2
    # or via shoulda
    d.should have_many(:cities)
 end
 end
 end
```

has you can see I used also [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) gem, do you think this approach is correct? I wrote too much test for this functions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance it appears you're focusing on testing state of the model objects. That's completely fine. The only thing I'd look at is do either of these models have any associated behavior? Do they contain any methods that implement business logic? If not, then you're home free, I believe. If you do, then I'd add tests for those behaviors.

Comment: right now i dont have any method about business logic, i was just testing rspec and i asked this cause i wanted a feedback about what I did, just to know if I'm on the right path. Thanks many

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest shoulda for testing your models:

When using rspec you should use shoulda-matchers gem in the test group of your gem file:

```
gem 'shoulda-matchers', :require => false
```

In your spec_helper.rb add the `require 'shoulda-matchers'` after `require 'rspec/rails'`.

Then you would simply use the following tests:

city_spec.rb

```
it { should validate_prescence_of(:name) }
it { should validate_prescence_of(:department_id) }
it { should belong_to(:department) }
```

For the uniqueness test you need to create an instance of city before the test but then you would use:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }
```

As you can see - much cleaner and clearer tests than what you have written.

Comment: how would you test "validates :account_id, :numericality => {:greater_then => 0}" using shoulda?

Comment: @Nazgob I would split the tests `it { should validate_numericality_of(:account_id) }` and then `it { should allow_value(0).for(:account_id) }` `it { should_not allow_value(-1).for(:account_id)`

Comment: ok, it would be nice to have it in one check though, idea for shoulda pull request? :)